# Converting codes written in Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python

I'm given a task of converting a bunch of codes written in Python 2.7 into Python 3.
So my question is
What are the fundamental differences between the two and what are the new features expected from conversion? I'm assuming it's not just syntactical issues.
Where should I start and what should I focus on?
It'll be more helpful if you could be as concrete as possible..
Please help me out and thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely start here: http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

For an automated tool, see: http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but how do you actually install it? I can't seem to find the download link..

Comment: I found http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/2to3/ but don't know what to do with the files to install it...

Comment: `2to3` should be *already* installed with your Python. If you can type `python` from a prompt and have it run, then you should also be able to run `2to3` the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Building from Greg's answer I find find it easier to grok the changes by looking at different compatibility layers people have built in order to support 2 and 3 in parallel.

- [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/), or specifically [this file](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/701f413a0d64/cherrypy/_cpcompat.py).
- [Six](http://packages.python.org/six/), or specifically [this file](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/be8eeca5bf0d/six.py).
- [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/), or specifically [this file](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/compat.py).

To use a compatibility layer or not is a widely discussed topic, however they are a good programmatic reference too scope the major changes and what you need to do in order to support them.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way is to use 2to3 and maintain two branches concurrently for a while. See [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k) article on the python.org wiki.

There's also an entire [website](http://python3porting.com/) with detailed information, which is basically the contents of a book on the subject.